# Bash: Do something with every PDF in folder

Tags: bash

I'm not familiar with the expansion of variables in bash. What I'm trying to do is:

I got a folder with lots of PDF, which I want to shrink in size. The command for a PDF 'foo.pdf' would be:

```
pdfsizeopt.py foo.pdf foo.pdf
```

How to do this to all pdf in the folder with a bash command?

```
for i in *.pdf; do pdfsizeopt.py $i.pdf $i.pdf; done
```

But pdfsizeopt.py complains, there were no pdf.

There are no filenames with spaces.

---

EDIT:
Thanks to [John](https://superuser.com/users/277295/john1024)! The line works! If I put it into a makefile, it doesn't (because I have no idea of such things):

```
compile:
     for i in *.pdf; do pdfsizeopt.py "$i" "$i"; done
```

I get:

```
for i in *.pdf; do pdfsizeopt.py "" ""; done
info: This is pdfsizeopt.py rUNKNOWN size=316003.
info: using Java for Multivalent: /usr/bin/java
info: loading PDF from: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/AW/bin/pdfsizeopt/pdfsizeopt.py", line 7835, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/home/AW/bin/pdfsizeopt/pdfsizeopt.py", line 7797, in main
    ).Load(file_name)
  File "/home/AW/bin/pdfsizeopt/pdfsizeopt.py", line 3440, in Load
    f = open(file_data, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
make: *** [compile] Fehler 1
```

Comment: Look at the top line in the output: `for i in *.pdf; do pdfsizeopt.py "" ""; done`.  It seems that `make` substituted in empty values for `$i` before `bash` got a hold of them.  From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/589296/3030305), you might try to force `make` to pass the line to bash unmangled by using: `bash -c 'for i in *.pdf; do pdfsizeopt.py "$i" "$i"; done'`.  If that doesn't work, you might make a new question with whatever tags are appropriate for `make`.

Comment: @John1024 Thank you very much, you were right, make "eats" one "$", so the solution for the makefile was: `compile: for i in *.pdf; do pdfsizeopt.py "$$i" "$$i"; done`; mind the double "$$" and there has to be a new line between "compile:" and the command, and the command has to be intended with a tab. Hey, great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `i` already has the extension in it:

```
for i in *.pdf; do pdfsizeopt.py "$i" "$i"; done
```

Separately, note that by putting the `$i` in double quotes, like `"$i"`, this code will now work for all manor of file names with spaces, tabs, or whatever.